# Can I use bash history modifiers with variables in scripts?

Tags: bash, history-expansion

It would be handy if I could use bash history modifiers in scripts such as:

`!$:h` to get the path of a file.

Is there a way to use them in scripts? Eg `${1:h}`

Comment: You're likely to shoot yourself in the foot going this way, this sounds like a XY problem, what is the problem you're trying to solve by using this ?

Comment: Have you tried just using them?

Comment: @Tensibai none really, just instead of doing variable substitution, I would like to take advantage of them

Comment: @cunninghamp3 no to be honest, but I know that history is disabled by default in scripts and I could not think of way to use the modifiers in variable expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those history modifiers could also be applied to variables in `csh` where the feature comes from.

But `bash` chose not to copy that part. `zsh` did though. So you could use `zsh` instead of `bash` here:

```
$ file=foo/bar/
$ echo $file:h # (or ${file:h})
foo
```

(the example chosen to show that `zsh` actually improved upon `csh` which would have returned `foo/bar` instead; it also supports quite a few additional useful modifiers).

In other shells, you can always use `dirname` instead:

```
$ dir=$(dirname -- "$file")
$ echo "$dir"
foo
```

(though beware it doesn't work correctly for directory names that end in newline characters).

In `bash`, like in other POSIX shells, you can use `${file%/*}` but it gives unexpected results in a few corner cases like that `foo/bar/` or `foo` or `/`.